# How to show button02 .kv-defined appearance upon button 01 on_press

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

im very much a learner!

i am learning python and kivy and currently working on a custom designed button.
i have defined 2 buttons in the .kv Rounded01 and Rounded02 as examples

all im trying to achieve is getting the defined settings for Rounded02 to display
on the Rounded01 button on_press and then revert on_release.

ive been through that many vids and webpages i cant quite see the forest for the trees lol
so im throwing myself on the mercy of you folks in the hope someone can show/help me with this final bit

PS - ive been working on this button for about 5 days lol learning and figuring out how to layer the canvas to display the design and these late nights have my eyes stinging lol

can a kind soul help a noob over the finish line?

PPS - i picked up along the way that i could use an image to achieve this in a much easier fashion but id like to ask you guys here if its possible before considering the easy route lol thanks!

## .PY code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineListItem
from kivy.core.window import Window

#designate our kv design file
Builder.load_file('shd_proto_kv_cfg.kv')


class Search(TwoLineListItem):
    pass


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class BaseLayout(Widget):
    pass


class ShdApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        return BaseLayout()


ShdApp().run()
```

## .kv code

```
<BaseLayout>
    BoxLayout:

        target_btn: trgbtn

        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        padding: 50
        spacing: 20

        Button:
            text: "!!! Hello Folks !!!"

        Rounded01:
            id: trgbtn
            text: "!!! im blue dab a dee dab a dai !!!"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: (1, .3)
            #on_press:
            #on_release:

        Rounded02:
            text: "!!! im green dab a dee dab a dai !!!"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint: (1, .3)


<Rounded01@Button>:
    id: bluebut
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (48/255, 84/255, 150/255, 1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [50]

<Rounded02@Button>:
    id: grnbut
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (34/255, 168/255, 74/255, 1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [50]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (255/255, 0/255, 0/255, 1)
        Line:
            rounded_rectangle: (self.pos[0], self.pos[1], self.size[0], self.size[1], 50)
            width: 2
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: (255/255, 0/255, 0/255, 1)
        Line:
            rounded_rectangle: (self.pos[0]+10, self.pos[1]+10, self.size[0]-20, self.size[1]-20, 50)
            width: 2
```

ive been through that many vids and webpages i cant quite see the forest for the trees lol
so im throwing myself on the mercy of you folks in the hope someone can show/help me with this final bit

all im trying to achieve is getting the defined settings for Rounded02 to display
on the Rounded01 button on_press and then revert on_release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hack that just uses duplicate code in the `kv` with conditionals:

```
<Rounded01@Button>:
    id: bluebut
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    blue_color: (48/255, 84/255, 150/255, 1)
    green_color: (34/255, 168/255, 74/255, 1)
    background_normal: ''
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.green_color if self.state == 'down' else self.blue_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [50]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (255/255, 0/255, 0/255, 1)
        Line:
            rounded_rectangle: (self.pos[0], self.pos[1], self.size[0], self.size[1], 50) if self.state == 'down' else (0,0,0,0,0)
            width: 2
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: (255/255, 0/255, 0/255, 1)
        Line:
            rounded_rectangle: (self.pos[0]+10, self.pos[1]+10, self.size[0]-20, self.size[1]-20, 50) if self.state == 'down' else (0,0,0,0,0)
            width: 2
```

Comment: ah nice one Mr Anderson! never thought of that, ive seen it a number of times tho! lol i will certainly play around with that is i might be able to utilize the " self.green_color if self.state == 'down' else self.blue_color " line with the other rgba values!  thanks very much for the help ill post back once ive had a chance to test and play around with that!! Awesome!! :)

Comment: Thats a bingo!!!!  had a quick play with this on the example i posted and i have it working!!!! just need to impliment it in my project but this looks to have solved it for me!!  Thank you again Mr Anderson!! so happy!! lol ( never thought id get this excited about trying to code a custom button lol

what worked -

Comment: this indeed worked :)

setting these values -

blue_color: (48/255, 84/255, 150/255, 1)
green_color: (34/255, 168/255, 74/255, 1)

then using the code to swap the colours when button is pressed -

self.green_color if self.state == 'down' else self.blue_color

has indeed worked :D